# How to relate water quality scores to land use percentages?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I have a question related to application of a linear mixed effect model.

I have land use data in percentage, which is the predictor, and a water quality score (e.g. 100) as response variable for 100 areas. However, for each area I have only one set of data both for predictors and response variable. I was wondering, can I use a linear mixed effect model to determine which land use is significantly contributing the water quality score? This question arises as I don't have repeated measures for each area. I am providing some of my data to better explain my question.

Data:

```
Ag.land  Forest  Urban_H  Urban_M   Urban_L  Wetland        Water quality score
Area-1    4.9      65      1.09      .18       .40       19.09           73.7
Area-2     6.73     19.72   24.28    0.36      1.91     27.61            57.03
```

Similarly, I have data for Area-3 up to Area-100.

Comment: Is your intention to learn about linear mixed models or to understand the relationships between water quality scores and land use? If it's the latter, then I recommend that you completely rewrite this post: drop all references to mixed models and ask instead about how you might create a useful model.

Comment: Whuber, Thank you very much! I want to understand the relationship between water quality score and land use matrices.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have repeated measures or spatial clustering then you don't need a mixed model. You can just use some (non-mixed) form of regression.

Of course, you could pose this as a mixed model with no random effect, but that wouldn't really be a mixed model. (That is, you could use e.g PROC MIXED in SAS to do a regular regression).